# ScrollSpy in WordPress stops working after navigating off the homepage

Tags: wordpress, navigation, navbar, scrollspy

Scrollspy links in the navigation bar stop working after navigating off of the homepage, which is because the URL for each one is a "#" as opposed to "website.com/about" (for an about page). How would I go about creating the URL needed for the navigation bar to work when the content I wish to navigate to is located on my homepage (ie. website.com/about, but about content is on the homepage)?

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbSuZ.png

Comment: I'm confused to what you are asking?  With scrollspy you would just set the link URL to match the ID of the element you want it to scroll to.

Comment: Yes, except there is no actual URL because you are anchoring it to the ID of the element (in picture). That element does not exist on the next page, therefor cannot access it because there is no URL to point to it. I'm asking how I would go about making my about section, display a URL of "website.com/about", so I can access it from another page.